# Postgres errors: where can I find a guide to these byte messages?

Tags: postgresql

I tried inserting a record into a Postgres database, and got a "key already exists" error message, in Go:

```
S:"ERROR" M:"duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"unique_name\"" n:"unique_name" 
F:"nbtinsert.c" L:"398" C:"23505" D:"Key (name)=(kevinburke) already exists." 
s:"public" t:"players" R:"_bt_check_unique"
```

It's clear that each of these fields has a meaning for Postgres. I've tried searching for documentation but I can't find anything online; where can I find out what each of the fields means?

(For reference, the string I am looking at is generated by the "pq" Go driver wrapper: https://github.com/bmizerany/pq/blob/master/error.go#L32)

Comment: There is a list of error messages at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html which might help, and they will also be in the code if you feel like searching for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of identification tokens and their meanings can be found here:

[Error and Notice Message Fields - Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/protocol-error-fields.html)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you're trying to auto-generate the primary key and your sequences have an incorrect value? If this makes no sense, could you post the query actually sent to the DB?